# How can I truncate text using a Vue filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue Filter to truncate my text when it becomes too long. However, I can not get it to work and have no idea why. Any help welcome.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'Bark bark and a woof woof'
  }
})

Vue.filter('truncate', function (value, size) {
  if (!value) return '';
  value = value.toString();

  if (value.length <= size) {
    return value;
  }
  return value.substr(0, size) + '...';
});
```

My HTML is as follows;

```
<div id="app">
 <p>{{text | truncate(8) }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: so what is the current result you get ? It still return the full text ?

Comment: Yes, It still returns the full text. https://jsfiddle.net/68jyhk0t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just check your fiddle, the reason is you need to declare the Filter before creating the Vue object

```
Vue.filter('truncate', function (value, size) {
  if (!value) return '';
  value = value.toString();

  if (value.length <= size) {
    return value;
  }
  return value.substr(0, size) + '...';
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'Bark bark and a woof woof'
  }
})
```

changing the order should works now